# check php for parse error without processing

Tags: php, parsing

I know that if I have a block of code as follows:

```
eval($code);
```

that if the code is not valid php, it will give me an error (and continue on).  What I normally do is this:

```
ob_start();
eval($code);
$err=ob_get_contents(); //none of the code I work with outputs HTML so this only catches errors
ob_end_clean();
if($err){
    //do something
}
```

however, IF THE CODE IS GOOD, then it will process.  Is there any way to determine of code will parse out correctly WITHOUT having it process?

Comment: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php#87762

Comment: php_check_syntax() is PHP 5 <= 5.0.4, so only an option if you're using a version of PHP where we'd be screaming at people to upgrade immediately if they were using it

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is the following:

1. Dump your `$code` to a temporary file.
2. Execute php using `exec( "php -l temporary_file_name" ) ;` - notice '-l' option (lint)
3. Check the output.
4. Delete temporary file.

If the output is empty then your code is correct.
If the output is non empty then it contains error description.

Here is an example of a code that can do that for you.
Notice that `sys_get_temp_dir()` is for php >= 5.2.1, and you need to use "" or "/tmp" instead if you have older php

```
function correct( $code, &$outarr ) {
  $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'phplint.' ) ;
  file_put_contents( $tmpfname, "<?php " . $code . " ?>" ) ;
  $dummy = exec( "php -l " . $tmpfname . " 2>&1", $outarr , $rv ) ;
  unlink( $tmpfname ) ;
  return ( $rv == 0 ) ;
}
```

And example of usage:

```
$code = "wrong=;" ;
if ( !correct( $code, $outarr )) {
  echo "Code is not correct \n" ;
  print_r( $outarr ) ;
}
```

You can, of course, play with `outarr`, to display better message or use even other methods to catch output like `ob_get_contents()`

I hope it will help.